# Right triangle where all sides are integer lengths, and the two smaller sides differ by 1

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, triangles

### Background

I'm currently taking a course in number theory and the following problem came up.

### Problem

> Find all the right triangles where the small sides differ by one.

### My Attempt

Let $\Delta ABC$ be my triangle with sides $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$.  Without loss of generality we can assume $a<b$, and thus $b=a+1$.

This gives the following equation: $2a^2+2a+1=c^2$, which I yet can't use. When reading another question on the site, a user gets to $a=\sqrt{b+c}$ when they assume $b=a+1$. They don't explain what is the process to get there.

I tried to obtain a solution, but could't get around the equations. The most I got to was $b^2-a^2=a+b$.

Now parametrizing the sides I get:

$
\begin{align}
    (a,b,c)  &= (m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)  \\ 
    &= (m^2-n^2,m^2-n^2+1,m^2+n^2) \\
    & =(2mn-1,2mn,m^2+n^2)
\end{align}
$

When I plug this solutions into the Pythagorean identity, I get curves with degree $4$ which I can't solve for any of the two variables. Even if I plug them into Mathematica, I get solutions with irrational numbers.

How can I find a solution to the equations? For example one of the curves is

$$m^4+n^4+6(mn)^2-4mn+1=0$$

When solving, I get a radical solution and I don't know how to make sure that it is an integer.

Any hints or comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: $a,b,c \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that.

Comment: Is it not assumed that the length are integers?

Comment: Something is wrong here.  You can make a right triangle with *any* $a \in \mathbb{N}$ with sides $a$, $a+1$ and $\sqrt{a^2 + (a+1)^2}$.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Just edited, $a, b, c$ are all integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the equation $$2a^2+2a+1=c^2$$

Hint : For this equation (quadratic in $a$) to posses integer solutions for $a$ and $c$,  it's discriminant must also be a perfect square.

$$\Delta = 8c^2-4=\lambda^2 $$

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm getting a Pell type equation from this. I'll work around and will post my results soon.

Comment: I solved it using that technique.  Check your solutions against $a = \{0, 3, 20, 119, 696, 4059, 23660, 137903, 803760, ... \}$.

Comment: @Ignacio Did you try to find out answers?

Comment: I did, had a bit of trouble with Pell's equation but now I have solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the Pythagorean triples $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ we require $m^2-n^2+1=2mn$ which leads to Pell's equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(m-n)^2-2n^2=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
A solution is $(m-n,n)=(3,2)$ leading to the triple $(21,20,29)$.

The next solution is $(m-n,n)=(17,12)$ leading to $(697,696,985)$.

Comment: You missed two solutions with smaller $a$ (see below).

Comment: Also, ($4$, $3$, $5$) is another triples